# Message shows as delivered only on one device

Tags: messages, text

What does it mean if I send a text to someone and it does not say delivered on my iPhone but it says delivered on my iPad? Does it mean the received it but not on their phone. I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

It probably just means that your two devices (iPhone and iPad) are not synced correctly with one another. My guess is that it doesn't actively search for whether the recipient received the message, only gets a "delivered" message on the device you sent it from. You could probably do a test check with texting a friend or family member's phone and compare how it responds from sending test messages from both devices.